# as3crypto encryption does not match C#/.NET

Tags: c#, actionscript, cryptography

Presently, I have this algorithm in C#/.NET:

```
    private static byte[] key = { };
    private static readonly byte[] IV = { 20, 52, 88, 120, 76, 89, 205, 239 };
    private static readonly string sEncryptionKey = "abcdefgh";

    public static string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("stringToEncrypt: " + stringToEncrypt);
            key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey.Substring(0, 8));
            Debug.WriteLine("key: " + Convert.ToBase64String(key));
            DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            //var des = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            des.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            Debug.WriteLine("inputByteArray: " + Convert.ToBase64String(inputByteArray));
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            Debug.WriteLine("IV: " + Convert.ToBase64String(IV));
            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            Debug.WriteLine("Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()): " + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()));
            return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

The problem is, I am trying to get the results of this algorithm to match the results of my ActionScript using as3crypto DES:

```
    protected function encrypt(input:String):String
    {
        var logData:Object = new Object();

        var decrKey:String = new String("abcdefgh");
        // byte[] IV = { 20, 52, 88, 120, 76, 89, 205, 239 };
        var iv:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        iv.writeByte(20);

        iv.writeByte(52);

        iv.writeByte(88);

        iv.writeByte(120);

        iv.writeByte(76);

        iv.writeByte(89);

        iv.writeByte(205);

        iv.writeByte(239);

        iv.position = 0;
        trace("iv: " + iv);         

        //var decrIV:String = iv.readUTF();
        var decrIV:String = new String();
        while (iv.bytesAvailable > 0) { 
            //read to letter or end of bytes 
            decrIV += iv.readUTFBytes(1);
        } 
        var inputBA:ByteArray=Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(input));
        var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(decrKey));
        var pad:IPad = new NullPad();
        var aes:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("des-cbc", key, pad);
        pad.setBlockSize(aes.getBlockSize());
        var ivmode:IVMode = des as IVMode;
        ivmode.IV = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(decrIV));
        des.encrypt(inputBA);

        return Base64.encodeByteArray( inputBA);
    }
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why they are different?  What am I missing?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

This is the ActionScript code I am now using, but as my comment indicates it is still different than the C# result:

```
    protected function encrypt(input:String):String
    {
        var logData:Object = new Object();

        var decrKey:String = new String("tuber$20");
        // byte[] IV = { 20, 52, 88, 120, 76, 89, 205, 239 };
        var iv:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        iv.writeByte(20);

        iv.writeByte(52);

        iv.writeByte(88);

        iv.writeByte(120);

        iv.writeByte(76);

        iv.writeByte(89);

        iv.writeByte(205);

        iv.writeByte(239);

        iv.position = 0;
        trace("iv: " + iv);         

        //var decrIV:String = iv.readUTF();
        var decrIV:String = new String();
        while (iv.bytesAvailable > 0) { 
            //read to letter or end of bytes 
            decrIV += iv.readUTFBytes(1);
        }
       //var inputBA:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(input));
        var inputBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
        inputBA.writeUTFBytes(input);

        //var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(decrKey));
        var key:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        inputBA.writeUTFBytes(decrKey);

        var pad:IPad = new NullPad();
        var aes:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("des-cbc", key, pad);
        pad.setBlockSize(aes.getBlockSize());
        var ivmode:IVMode = aes as IVMode;
        //ivmode.IV = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(decrIV));
        ivmode.IV = new ByteArray();
        inputBA.writeUTFBytes(decrIV);

        aes.encrypt(inputBA);

        return Base64.encodeByteArray( inputBA);
    }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Thank you, @Miguel Sanchez.  If I break each down and compare their output, they are identical except for the very last encryption:

```
    protected function encrypt(input:String):String
    {
        trace("stringToEncrypt: " + input);                     
        var logData:Object = new Object();

        var decrKey:String = new String("tuber$20");
        // byte[] IV = { 20, 52, 88, 120, 76, 89, 205, 239 };
        var iv:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        iv.writeByte(20);

        iv.writeByte(52);

        iv.writeByte(88);

        iv.writeByte(120);

        iv.writeByte(76);

        iv.writeByte(89);

        iv.writeByte(205);

        iv.writeByte(239);

        iv.position = 0;
        trace("iv: " + Base64.encodeByteArray(iv));         

        //var decrIV:String = iv.readUTF();
        var decrIV:String = new String();
        while (iv.bytesAvailable > 0) { 
            //read to letter or end of bytes 
            decrIV += iv.readUTFBytes(1);
        }
        trace("decrIV: " + decrIV);

        //var inputBA:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(input));
        var inputBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
        inputBA.writeUTFBytes(input);
        trace("inputBA: " + Base64.encodeByteArray(inputBA));       

        //var key:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(decrKey));
        var key:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        key.writeUTFBytes(decrKey);
        trace("key: " + Base64.encodeByteArray(key));   

        var pad:IPad = new NullPad();
        var aes:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("des-cbc", key, pad);
        pad.setBlockSize(aes.getBlockSize());
        var ivmode:IVMode = aes as IVMode;
        //ivmode.IV = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(decrIV));
        ivmode.IV = new ByteArray();
        ivmode.IV.writeUTFBytes(decrIV);
        trace("ivmode.IV: " + Base64.encodeByteArray(ivmode.IV));

        aes.encrypt(inputBA);

        trace("Base64.encodeByteArray(inputBA): " + Base64.encodeByteArray(inputBA));
        return Base64.encodeByteArray(inputBA);
    }
```

Here is the output from the ActionScript:

```
stringToEncrypt: a1d63a1fb90b422ecce953b3302b6e521f96
key: dHViZXIkMjA=
inputBA: YTFkNjNhMWZiOTBiNDIyZWNjZTk1M2IzMzAyYjZlNTIxZjk2
iv: FDRYeExZze8=
decrIV: 4XxLYÍï
ivmode.IV: FDRYeExZw43Drw==
Base64.encodeByteArray(inputBA): 6AJu1PUFRHx+Ykf0r1HlZVy39kR0HrOaw+wTHmnRPPunisp4TR0cSw==

stringToEncrypt: 10:00
key: dHViZXIkMjA=
inputBA: MTA6MDA=
iv: FDRYeExZze8=
decrIV: 4XxLYÍï
ivmode.IV: FDRYeExZw43Drw==
Base64.encodeByteArray(inputBA): N5VgWd0Ccu0=
```

Here is the output from C#/.NET:

```
stringToEncrypt: a1d63a1fb90b422ecce953b3302b6e521f96
key: dHViZXIkMjA=
inputByteArray: YTFkNjNhMWZiOTBiNDIyZWNjZTk1M2IzMzAyYjZlNTIxZjk2
IV: FDRYeExZze8=
Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()): h2jT8xR2SOPagrQwF3leuKFdEvHpYyfCUzEJw2lxXG2HnuUyw1QXzg==

stringToEncrypt: 10:00
key: dHViZXIkMjA=
inputByteArray: MTA6MDA=
IV: FDRYeExZze8=
Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()): WVOOknAikYs=
```

**UPDATE 3:**

This is the ActionScript code for the last steps:

```
    aes.encrypt(inputBA);

    return Base64.encodeByteArray(inputBA);
```

This is the C#/.NET code for the last steps:

```
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
```

Comment: In `as3` why are you using the  `Hex` functions for converting `String` to `ByteArray` why not use `ByteArray.writeUTFBytes()`

Comment: If I change the first Hex line to this: "var inputBA:ByteArray=ByteArray.writeUTFBytes(input);" I get the error: "Line 222, Column 45 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method writeUTFBytes through a reference with static type Class."

Comment: `var inputBA:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); inputBA.writeUTFBytes(input);`

Comment: OK, now I get this from C#: h2jT8xR2SOPagrQwF3leuKFdEvHpYyfCUzEJw2lxXG2HnuUyw1QXzg== and this from ActionScript: +KZVDXO6+1bIC3IgPqxh6j1lsiJK/rXPnKHpH84Gd5nZcJ3bdp1aRvhtF+moz5WMPzYgCMIrk7Y=  they are still different.

Comment: have you changed both lines using `Hex`, I mean for `inputBA` and for `key`?

Comment: Please see my update above.

Comment: You need to add traces / console.writeline at each step and see the bytearray output for `AS3` and `C#` and compare them, you will surely find the error then, basically make a function to dump the contents of the ByteArray both in `as3` and `c#` and then compare them at each step.

Comment: the line after ` var key:ByteArray = new ByteArray();` is wrong it should be `key.writeUTFBytes(decrKey);`

Comment: Thank you.  For every ActionScript ByteArray, I use like "trace("inputBA: " + inputBA);" but the output for all ByteArray objects is the same, "iv: 4XxLYÍï" "ivmode.IV: 4XxLYÍï" "ivmode.IV: 4XxLYÍï"  How do I view the actual contents of ByteArray in Adobe CC IDE?

Comment: have you corrected that line after ` var key:ByteArray = new ByteArray();` as per my comment above?

Answer (score 1):

First change this line

```
inputBA.writeUTFBytes(decrKey);
```

to

```
key.writeUTFBytes(decrKey);
```

You may need some function like this to print a `ByteArray` in `AS3`.

```
public static function fromArray(array:ByteArray, colons:Boolean=false):String {
        var s:String = "";
        for (var i:uint=0;i<array.length;i++) {
                s+=("0"+array[i].toString(16)).substr(-2,2);
                if (colons) {
                        if (i<array.length-1) s+=":";
                }
        }
        return s;
}
```

Sources: [AS3 ByteArray to Hex representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974043/as3-bytearray-to-hex-binary-hex-representation)

Comment: So, I should be using "trace("inputBA: " + fromArray(inputBA));"   instead of the code like "trace("inputBA: " + Base64.encodeByteArray(inputBA));"?

Comment: @user89861 are you doing Base64 encoding for some reason? I mean is it only to trace or is it necessary in your code?

Comment: Otherwise in trace it just outputs the type like byte[] instead of the actual contents of the byte array.

Comment: @user89861 all the traces seem equal so something seems wrong in the last step, so only concentrate on that for now

Comment: @user89861 can you post the c# and as3 code for the last step?

Comment: Please see UPDATE 3 above.

Comment: @user89861 there seems to be something wrong with your as3 code look at this article and use that class and then compare your results with c# [AS3Cryto with DES](http://onethingor2.blogspot.in/2014/04/use-as3crypto-for-des.html)